# Showing that this process is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a Markov chain $\{X_n\}$, with the states $S=\{0,1\}$ and the probability matrix

$$p_{11}=1-a \quad p_{12}=a \quad p_{21}=b \quad p_{22}=1-b \quad 0<a, b<1$$

I want to show that the stochastic process $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n) \quad n \geq 1,$ is the Markov chain and write its probability matrix.

I don't know where to start and what does it really mean that $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $4$ states for $Z_n$, namely
$$
(1,1),\;\;(1,2),\;\;(2,1),\;\;(2,2)
$$
For example, $Z_n$ is in state $(1,2)$ when $X_{n-1}=1$ and $X_n=2$.

Note that the value of $X_{n-1}$ plays no role in the transition from $Z_n=(X_{n-1},X_n)$ to $Z_{n+1}=(X_n,X_{n+1})$.

Based on that observation, I've filled in the second row of the transition probability matrix for $Z_n$.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&(1,1)&(1,2)&(2,1)&(2,2)\\
\hline
(1,1)&&&&\\
\hline
(1,2)&0&0&b&1-b\\
\hline
(2,1)&&&&\\
\hline
(2,2)&&&&\\
\hline
\end{array}
In the above example, from state $(1,2)$, the next state must be either $(2,1)$ or $(2,2)$, and the probabilities for those two outcomes are $p_{21}$ and $p_{22}$ respectively.

See if you can fill in the rest.

Comment: I understand that in this example states will be (0,0),(0,1),(1,0) and (1,1), because the states are denoted by zero and one. Now I filled in the second row with: 0,0,a*b,b*(1-b). Is it correct?

Comment: Ok I see now I don't think correctly. Can you please explain for eample one the transisition (1,2) -> (2,1) why is it (1-b)? Thank you a lot!

Comment: and if the tranistion from (1,2) to (2,1) is p_{21}=b why there is (1-b) in the table?

Comment: State $Z_n=(1,2)$ means $X_{n-1}=1$ and $X_n=2$. But $Z_{n+1}$ has first coordinate $X_n$ which is equal to $2$ (no choice), but the second coordinate of $Z_{n+1}$ is $X_{n+1}$ which is is probabilistic, based on the transition probabilities for $X_n$, namely $p_{21}$ and $p_{22}$.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the edit! :) So I understand that the matrix will be: 1st row and 4th ((1-a),a,0,0) and 2nd and 4th row (0,0,b,1-b)?

Comment: Yes, you got it.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks so much! And is it enough to also show that the Z_n is indeed the Markov Chain?

Comment: If the transition probabilities from each state sum to $1$ then it's a Markov chain (i.e., each row has nonnegative entries which sum to $1$).

Comment: Also note: You've labeled the transition probabilities for $X_n$ as $p_{11},p_{12},p_{21},p_{22}$ which means the states $1,2$, not $0,1$.

Comment: Yes you're right, my mistake! Thanks for the help. I understand it now.